# Get synonyms of a word from Thesaurus using Google Sheets importxml function

Tags: xpath, spreadsheet, synonym

I am trying to make a dictionary that includes one synonym for each word on Google Sheets. I wish that I can get only first synonym on the Thesaurus search result page, by copying XPath and pasting it to the importxml function. Could anybody help me getting the entire function that I can apply to all of my words? (hundreds of words so I need automation).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahL7W.png]

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this (first we concat to generate the URL, then we pass the XPath expression:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/"&B2;"(//h2)[1]/following::li[1]//text()")
```

Output:

[image: Syn]

---

To get 3 synonyms in one cell, use :

```
=TEXTJOIN(";";VRAI;IMPORTXML("https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/"&B2;"(//h2)[1]/following::li[position()<4]//text()"))
```

Output:

[image: 3S]

Comment: Thank you so much! Then how can I get three topmost synonyms? Like, if I want to get "assume, consider, determine" on cell C2 for a word "think" on cell B2?

Comment: For some reason I get the css instead. _".css-1kg1yv8{cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;text-align:center;-webkit-text-decoration:none;text-decoration:none;border-radius:100px;font-size:16px;font-weight:inherit;line-height:1;text-align:left;-webkit-transition:all 
0.25s ease-in-out;transition:all 0.25s ..."_ . How to solve this?

Comment: You're getting that CSS because the XPATH is different now. As of right now, you would need to replace everything between those final quotes with this:


`//*[@id='meanings']/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/text()`